# Get shades of Color in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

Is there a way in `Javascript` or `jQuery` that we can get all shades of a color and then return the values into an `array`? Thank you very much.

Something like:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example color?

Comment: And what are you expecting as a sample output?

Comment: I added an image on the question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
var r = 40 % 256;
var g = 40 % 256;
var b = 50 % 256;
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    r += 33;
    g += 33;
    b += 33;
    result.push(r + "," + g + "," + b);
}
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Oh shoot I should try this right now! Thanks for the answer. Testing it.

Comment: Thank you very much dude! It worked! :D Have a nice day

Answer (score 9):

[In color theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tints_and_shades?wprov=sfla1), to get a `shade` of a color you need to reduce its lightness, and to get a `tint` of a color you need to increase its lightness. I've created [a library](https://elchininet.github.io/ColorTranslator/), that allows you to work with the  `HSL` color model. With this color model, you can take a base color and change its hue, lightness, or saturation. Here you have something similar to your purposes using the `getTints` method:

```js
const { ColorTranslator } = colortranslator;
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const tints = ColorTranslator.getTints("#93625D", 15);

tints.forEach((c) => {
  const box = document.createElement("div");
  box.style.backgroundColor = c;
  container.appendChild(box);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(tints));
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

#container div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/colortranslator@1.10.1/web/colortranslator.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Here you have another example that changes the saturation and lightness of a color at the same time to get all the tints of each saturation:

```js
const { ColorTranslator } = colortranslator;
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const color = new ColorTranslator('hsl(25,100%,50%)');
let box = null;

//---Create elements
for (let row = 0; row < 10; row++) {

  for (let col = 0; col < 10; col++) {

    color
      .setS(row * 10)
      .setL(col * 5 + 30);

    box = document.createElement("div");
    box.style.background = color.HEX;
    box.innerText =
      `R:${color.R}
       G:${color.G}
       B:${color.B}`;
    container.appendChild(box);

  }

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 500px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}

#container div {
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 10%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/colortranslator@1.10.1/web/colortranslator.js"></script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Very clear and very thoughtful. Thank you.